# Video-js tag autoplay HLS Live stream

Tags: html, http-live-streaming, video.js

I am live streaming via videojs. The stream works but I am unable to get it to autoplay. Instead I need to click the play button each time I go on the page.

```
<video-js id="my_video" autoplay controls preload="auto" width="762" height="428" poster="images/poster2.jpg">
          <source src="http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:1935/live/xxxxx/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
          </video-js>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/http-streaming/dist/videojs-http-streaming.js"></script>

  <script>
    var player = videojs('my_video');
    video.autoplay = true
  </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Many browsers won't allow autoplay now unless the video is muted. You can add the `muted` attribute.

You can also use the `any` option for autoplay, in which case the video will be autoplayed with sound if possible, if not then autoplayed muted if that is possible. Remove the `autoplay` attribute and use a setup option instead:

```
var player = videojs('my_video', {autoplay: 'any'});
```

Comment: I've just tried this but unfortunately I still get the play button

Answer (score 0):

```
var options, player;

options = {
    controls: true,
    autoplay:'any',
    techOrder: [ 'chromecast', 'html5' ],
    plugins: {
        chromecast: {}
    }
};

player = videojs(document.getElementById('vjs'), options, function() {
        player.chromecast();
    });
```